# passing parameter in ios5 storyboard segue + UITableview

Tags: xcode, ios5, uitableview

I was to pass a NSString from RootViewController(UITableViewController) to DetailViewController .

t RootViewController.m

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { 
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController; 
    detailViewController.name = @"foo"; 
    }
```

DetailViewController.h:

```
NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;
```

DetailViewController.m

```
@synthesize name = _name;
NSLog(@"%@", name);
```

The result of NSlog is null. Appreciate for any hint. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really see when you are executing your nslog. So i'm thinking you ask for the name before you are setting it.

And another thing. If you write:

```
@synthesize name = _name;
```

you should use this too:

```
NSLog(@"%@", _name);
```

Comment: eeks... i should die... Thanks Sharky!

Answer (score 0):

you can view the sample passing data from `cell` to `detailViewController` [at YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_JaeXGqwhI).

Comment: ...for those who don't speak Spanish, the video is (helpfully) in Spanish, and the resolution is terrible. Thoroughly unhelpful!